# Is it possible to serialize a grouped list?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, serialization

I want to serialize grouped list. but I am getting error. Is it possible to serialize a grouped list? if yes then How?

Error :

```
Cannot serialize interface System.Linq.IGrouping`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[MyProject.MyNamespace.Elements, MyProject.MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

Code :

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
List<IGrouping<string, Elements>> lstGroupedElements = listElements.GroupBy(member=> member.Type).ToList();               
XmlSerializer objXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IGrouping<string, Elements>>));
objXmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, lstGroupedElements);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The grouping information is redunded and doesn’t need to be saved. You can just save the list (without grouping) and add the grouping when you deserialize it.

Comment: Actually I want generate xml file with grouped elements. I know there are many ways to do it. But my question is "Is it possible to serialize a grouped list?"

Comment: Yes… but you have to build you own group structure/class. Because you can’t serialize Interfaces. How should the deserialization work? It can’t do `new IGrouping()` because it’s an Interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t serialize `Interface`s, because there is no way to restore them. For the Deserialization something like `new IGrouping()` would be needed and that’s not possible. So you have to build your own Grouping Structure, which holds the group name and its elements.

```
listElements.GroupBy(member=> member.Type)
            .Select(g => new MyGrouping() {GroupName = g.Key, Elements = g.ToList()})
            .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

MyGrouping could look like this:

```
public class MyGrouping
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

or when you want a flattened XML implement some Interfaces:

```
public class MyGrouping : Collection<Element>, IGrouping<string, Element>
{
    …
}
```

Comment: what is MyGrouping? How Can I arrange this in my code?

Comment: It’s just a Class that holds your grouping information and Elements, which you can serialize and deserialize. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: I used your method to get this working for ASP.Net Web API. I need some events grouped by year -- it worked great! My Web API is simply:  public IEnumerable<MyGrouping> GetProductEvents()
        {
            IEnumerable<MyGrouping> groups = 
                db
                    .Products
                    .GroupBy(x => x.EventDateTimeUTC.Year)
                    .Select(g => new MyGrouping { Year = g.Key, Events = g.ToList() })
            ;
            return groups;
        }  Then I get a nice XML load that I can consume with JQuery, etc.