# Problem with deserializing the grouped data (json)

Tags: c#, json, linq, serialization, deserialization

I have a problem (seems to be basic) with showing deserialized JSON data into `datagridview`.

I have a simple `Person` class:

```cs
class Person
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string school { get; set; }     
}
```

And a list of five people:

```cs
Person p1 = new Person() { age = 12, name = "Peter", school = "s1" };
Person p2 = new Person() { age = 13, name = "Jack", school = "s2" };
Person p3 = new Person() { age = 14, name = "William", school = "s2" };
Person p4 = new Person() { age = 15, name = "Emily", school = "s2" };
Person p5 = new Person() { age = 16, name = "Sophie", school = "s1" };
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>() { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 };
```

and grouping on this list:

```cs
var result = from n in persons group n by n.school;
```

Then (**the problem is here**) i have a serializing/deserializeing process:

```cs
var serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
var deserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized);
```

And unfortunately I cannot show the deserialized result (should be "s1" and "s2" in this example) in a `datagridview`:

```cs
//failed! :(
dataGridView1.DataSource = deserialized;
```

Where is the problem? 
**Note1:** its a simple demonstration of my problem. in real program, i have no access to "persons". and the field names (age, name, school,...) are unknown. all i have is the serialized data (form of "result" variable). in other words, "result" variable is a black box.
**Note2:** as far as i know, the problem only occurs in grouped data. so every thing will goes fine if the "result" (black box) doesn't contains grouping. but my problem is about deserializing the grouped data.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you Deserialiizing with a Type like this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(string json);`? If not, try it.

Comment: Is it a similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926717/is-it-possible-to-serialize-a-grouped-list If so you will need to create your own grouping structure as suggested.

Comment: @sr28 there is no error but datagridview remains empty! i will check that link (grouping structure). thanks

Comment: What are you expecting the DataGridView to show in this case? How should it present, in practice, the Grouping? Maybe an `OrderBy(p => p.school)` would do?

Comment: @Jimi in this example, i expect the single column with two rows (with these values: "s1", "s2") in datagridview.
Note: everything goes fine if i pass "result" to datagridview without serializatin. the problem occurs after serializing/deserializing process)

Comment: Then don't serialize the grouping, serialize the `persons` List. If you deserialize the grouping, you get a jagged array: `Person[][]`. If you don't group, you get back a `List<Person>`. Deserialize it and perform the grouping on the result: `dataGridView1.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(serialized).GroupBy(p => p.school).ToList();`

Comment: @jimi 
still not works... (throws an exception)

Comment: Of course it works, why wouldn't it? You didn't follow what I wrote: Serialize the `List<Person>`, deserialize the JSON to a `List<Person>`, perform the grouping, using `deserialized.GroupBy(p => p.school).ToList()` (on the returned List), show the results, setting the DGV's DataSource. That's all.

Comment: @Jimi
sorry, you are right. that works but my problem persists. why? because i have no access to "result" (and "persons") in my original code... "persons" is in another appdomain and all i have is the serialized form of that. in other words, in my original program i'm going to pass the grouped data into another appdomain via json serialization/deserialization and show them in datagridview (the datagridview is in the second appdomain)

Comment: Well, I don't know why would you send the data like that; anyway, deserialize to `Person[][]`, then `dataGridView1.DataSource = deserialized.SelectMany(p => p.Select(s => new { School = s.school })).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: @Jimi
there is red squiggly line under Select ('Person' doesn't contain a definition for 'Select'...) but my problem is much more than this. in my original program the type of data (grouped/ non grouped/ projected/...) will be defined in runtime. therefor the field names are unknown. in addition, all of that are in another appdomain... so i'm looking for a general (and flexible) way to show the deserialized data in datagridview without knowing the data field names ('school' for example)

Comment: You didn't deserialize to `Person[][]` (jagged array) or `List<Person[]>`, you tried to deserialize to `Person[]`. About the rest, I'll think about it. But your question is lacking a great amout of details which came up just in comments. I'm also not sure why you provided this: `var result = from n in persons group n by n.school;`, since, apparently, the `school` key is not known. When you serialize like that, the key is lost.

Comment: you are right. my question was not clear (i made some changes on it). my program is for working with databases. the user (in runtime) writes a conditions (with 'where', 'select', 'group',...) and get the result in datagridview. what user writs is unknown for me. i only have access to serialized form of data that created by user. in this simplified example, i don't know any thing about "person" and "result". i just have a string of serialized data and should find a way to show that correctly in datagridview.
Note: the problem only occurs in grouping! everything goes fine in non-grouped data

Comment: Sound like you are opening up to SQL Injection to me...

Comment: @sr28
nes (yes+no)!... its not about SQL injection but has similarities

Answer (score 1):

your problem here is that you are not specifying the type of deserialization you want.

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Person>>>(serialized)
```

and this should do the trick

Comment: Problem was my fault, it does work like this but with a twist, since when you re grouping you are making another list of your lists. So in order to work you have to make another nest of list. i ll edit the post

Comment: thanks. but the problem persists.. 
now some information shows in datagridview but is meaningless for me! the datagridview shows two column (capacity - cout) and shows some numbers on it! i don't know the meaning of that numbers (and also that column headers...)

Comment: well that is because you re printing the raw data you are getting, my guess is capacity is the amount of records that the json have (from 0 to 4 its 5), and the second thing is the amout of records that belong to s1, and the amount of records that belong to s2. If you tell me what you do want to do with that info you group perhaps i can help you shape it

Comment: the result is:
Capacity-Count/
4-2/
4-3/

Comment: if you put a break point in the deserialized variable and advance you will see that its a list, with 2 objects, [0] does contain 2 more objects, which are your records for peter and sophie. and [1] does contain 3 records, which are the other 3 records. What do you intend to do with this information? What do you want to show in the data grid view?

Comment: good suggestion but i'm looking for the simpler (and more general) solution.. because in my original program, the data will be defined in runtime and i should find the way to handle any type of data (grouped/ non grouped/ projected/...) and show them in datagridview...

Comment: the problem is that you have to know what kind of data you are getting in order to properly deserialize it. Then you can do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: yes, its a huge problem. but what is surprising is that this method works like a charm for any non-grouped data. the problem only occurs in grouping...

Comment: That is because you are adding a new layer to the json, another list inside of an already made list. Your [0] is the s1 group, and your [1] is your s2 group. but this wont matter at all if someone can make n subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Nalnpir's suggestion is correct. You'll need to specify a type inorder to deserialize the json. Have you tried creating a binding source from and setting the data source as a list?

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(serialized)
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = list;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: message is:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array(e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WindowsFormsApplication50.Person' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.{"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object(e.g.{"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array.JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0]',line 1,position 2.

Comment: Ahh, Ok. So when you perform your grouped by your type is no longer List, but System.Linq.GroupedEnumberable. When you serialize your result there are extra brackets separating each group that cause the error. Ultimately, I don't think this approach would work for you as the datasource property of the datagridview wouldn't be able to determine the cols/rows of the source.